# compare common values in list with unequal sublist elements

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a tibble like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
    id = 1:3,
    names = c("George G|Nick N", "Nick N|Andrian A", "Era E")

)
```

The `names` column has unequal length of names.

I want to extract those names and compare if there are any common names.

Extracting:

```
df_names <- (lapply(df$names, function(x) {strsplit(x, split="|", fixed = TRUE)}))
```

Now, I am not sure how to proceed to the comparison.

I tried something like:

```
maxlength <- max(sapply(df_names, length))
lapply(seq(maxlength),function(i) Reduce(intersect, lapply(df_names,"[[",i)))
```

but returns an empty character list.

By common names, I mean , as we can see `df_names[[1]]` and `df_names[[2]]` have the common name `Nick N`.

Then, I can group by id for example and plot id vs common names, to see which ids have common names.

An example plot:

[image: plot]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "common names"? You mean between entries? Could you illustrate what the desired result would look like?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik:Hi, I updated the post. I am not sure about the exact final result, just be able to show in plot for example as I say in the post.

Comment: You'll make your life easier if you reformat your data like this:  `df %>%  mutate(names = strsplit(names, "|", fixed = TRUE)) %>%   tidyr::unnest(names)`

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a matrix with cells showing a presence of common names between ids.

For example:

```
library(proxy)
df <- df %>% mutate(sep_names = strsplit(names, split="|", fixed = TRUE))

res <- proxy::dist(df$sep_names, method = function(x, y) any(x %in% y))

# Convert to matrix and assign ids
res <- as.matrix(res)
colnames(res) <- df$id
rownames(res) <- df$id

# > res == 1
#       1     2     3
# 1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# 2  TRUE FALSE FALSE
# 3 FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

As for plotting, you can start from this:

```
library(reshape2)
ggplot(melt(res == 1), aes(Var1,Var2, fill=value)) +
    geom_raster() +
    scale_fill_discrete() +
    xlab("id") + ylab("id")
```

Comment: And then how can I plot the common names vs ids?

Comment: In the plot, in y axis I want to show the names , not false/true values

Comment: Alright, can you explain that more clearly? On the x-axis we have ids. What about y-axis? Should it contain all possible names? If so, each cell should depict if that name is present in the corresponding id and simultaneously is common with any other id?

Comment: On x axis we have ids, y axis will contain only the common names.So, in our case, x axis will contain id 1 and 2 and y axis will contain Nick N.I hope it is clear, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, your explanation is not clear. You described two points on the x-axis and one point on the y-axis. How to show that they are connected (have a common name)? Then, what about other points. Can you describe a graph for the situation with 3 ids, when all of them have common names and those names are different? I.e. for example, 1 has common `Nik` with 3, 3 has common 'Ben' with 2, 1 has common 'George' with 2?